# How can I convince my at-risk employees to come to the office?

Tags: professionalism, management, software-development, unprofessional-behavior

A few of the developers at my company want to work from home because they have "pre-existing conditions" that mean they are "at risk" from COVID.

I am firmly against this, as I think they are more effective at the office.  I am concerned that working from home, they are not as productive.

What can I do to convince them that coming in is safe?

Failing that, is there some way I can gauge their performance, either through software or metrics to identify anyone not meeting their obligations?

Comment: Your country? And what powers do you have over them?

Comment: How do you tell whether a developer is slacking off? I have done some of my best work staring out the window or playing solitaire.

Comment: The first question to answer... IS it safe? How do you know? In the US the virus is spreading wildly again as people start to gather more and more. What precautions does your workplace have to ensure the risk is mitigated?

Comment: @teego1967 and, more importantly, despite all the precautions, what guarantee do they have of not getting infected?

Comment: @SouravGhosh, at this point I don't think anyone is guaranteed of not getting infected. The best thing people can do in workplaces is strict social distancing, temperature screening, 1 person in restroom at a time, no communal food/coffee, no conf-room meetings, etc. At my workplace in NJ we're at 50% capacity and people have rolling schedules to come in 2-3 days a week. There are protocols to close the office for 2 weeks if anyone gets covid-19. Is it a guarantee, no, but close enough if people observe the rules.

Comment: @teego1967 Agree. I was not contesting your comment, rather adding to it. This question is more of a psychological matter, rather than physical measures.

Comment: I don't think you can really measure developer productivity anyways.

Comment: @SouravGhosh, indeed, there's a psychological component. I think the OP could put a completely different spin on this by actually addressing what safety measures the workplace can commit to. If he were to bring up 99% survivability (as a main argument), that would absolutely crater any chances of "convincing" anyone.

Answer (score 10):

Question for you: do you want to keep any employees? With all due respect[1], you sound like a terrible manager to work for. You don't have trust in your employees, and you are willing to put them at risk for marginal productivity gains.

My advice: change your attitude.

<sup>1. I refer you to Sir Humphrey Appleby.</sup>

Comment: Could this be phrased in a more politik manner? :O

Comment: @Fattie I'm sure it _could_. I prefer the direct approach though :-)

Answer (score 6):

Let me re-iterate what you just said:

> *I am firmly against this, as **I think** they are more effective at the office and **I can see** if they're slacking off.*

1. "I think" has no business in a professional decision making, it must be based on facts. Unless you have sufficient data to prove your point, don't jump to conclusion and make decisions based on that. The only direction it can go is south.
2. If you need to "see" (i.e. watch over) the employees to track their productivity, you need a better management (process and tools), not physical presence. I'm not sure how big of a team you manage / oversee, any number beyond 3 cannot be managed this way.

You need to find a way to trust your employees, and at the same time, make sure the work is done. Unless you work in a specific field / domain, where physical presence is mandatory to get the work done - I do not see any valid argument for your thought process.

To sum it up, you don't need to convince them, you need to convince yourself to equip a better management process and switch to result-driven mindset.

Comment: Interesting...I hope to see some comments explaining why this is not a useful answer. Waiting to learn something new.:)

Comment: I think it's a fair enough answer.

Comment: I view it as a more nuanced (and probably more helpful) version of my answer ;-)

Answer (score 3):

It's a sensitive matter. Ultimately you should think about the cost benefit analysis of the situation.

1. Employees come to the office

   - Benefit: you can see that they are working
   - Cost: employees less physically safe
2. Employees stay at home

   - Benefit: employees more physically safe
   - Cost: you can't see *if* they're slacking off.

To me, the costs of forcing them into the office outweigh the benefits of satisfying yourself if they are working or not, but you may feel differently.

Ultimately there is no easy way - if you want them to come in you will need to force them to.

Comment: You should probably add "employees ARE not physically safe" to the list of cons :)

Comment: @Erik - I thought that was obvious.

Comment: It should be, but given that the question is asked, apparently it isn't, so it's best to be explicit :)

Answer (score 2):

> that this virus has a 99% survival rate.

Overall, yes. If you have pre-existing conditions that number rapidly drops. If you have asthma for example, you might only have a 97% survival rate. If you are 80 years old, you might only have an 80% survival rate. If you are caring for elderly parents or grandparents, it might be fine for you, but you could easily spread it to them.

Why can’t you just move to a results driven work environment? Wouldn’t a lack of finished work that show if any employee were slacking?

Comment: "Survival" isn't enough. Large enough numbers of people suffer serious health impacts from this virus. Moreover, the risk gets passed to more vulnerable populations. A outbreak at the office might not "kill" an employee, but it could spread, perhaps with fatal consequences, to friends or family and the workplace would be morally responsible for that.

Comment: While this answer goes into the right direction, one more reason to be cautious even as a unattached young person with no preconditions is that we know very little about long term damage or side effects of infection, and what we do know so far isn't very encouraging. It's not a wise move to take getting it lightly.